# using Laravel to reset password by mail gives swiftmailer error code 550 (no such user)

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

Using Laravel 5.7 (or 5.6), with Valet. Trying to use Password reset mail functionality but this gives an error message.

`http://myproject.test/password/reset`

In both cases (actual ISP or mailtrap.io) I get an error message:

```
Swift_TransportException (550)
Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 5.1.0 No such user [3844] "
```

My .env (mailtrap.io):

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=<mailtrap username>
MAIL_PASSWORD=<mailtrap password>
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Always same message, also after entering dummy username/password. Also tried `php artisan serve` instead of Valet, and tried production Apache httpd.

Suggestions?

Comment: Did you try php artisan config:cache command?

Comment: Did you edited something on `config/mail.php` ? if so, show it... Also, are you using the mailtrap.io user/password or your mailtrap.io INBOX user and password?